# Why was Bane expelled from the League of Shadows?

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises

In *The Dark Knight Rises* it is said that Bane was expelled from the League of Shadows. Is it known why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no mention of Bane being expelled because of how he looks.  From the script:

```
WAYNE
Bane was a member of the League of Shadows?

ALFRED
Until he was excommunicated. And a
man considered too extreme for Ra's al Ghul
is not to be trifled with.
```

So the only thing we have to go on is that his methods were considered too extreme even for the League.

Of course later in the movie he cast's doubt on whether he really was expelled:

```
BANE
But we are initiated, aren't we,
Bruce? The League of Shadows. And
you betrayed us...
                     
BATMAN
Us? You were excommunicated. From a
gang of psychopaths.

BANE
Now I am the League of Shadows,
here to fulfill Ra's al Ghul's destiny...
```

And of course later we find he is working for Talia, Ra's al Ghul's daughter.  Misdirection is one of the League's core techniques.

So in short, its not clear whether he was really expelled or not, and there is no documented reason other than 'he was too extreme'.

Comment: In the context of the film, there is nothing disputing the fact that he was excommunicated. He could be working for Talia without being part of the League of Shadows. Or, more likely, he is starting Talia’s own splinter faction of the League of Shadows to carry on her perceived view of her father’s legacy.

Comment: @DeanF. ... I don't disagree. There's Alfred's research, and there is Bane's own claim of 'being the League of Shadows', which could be a disputing claim, or (as you say) his own faction.  Its quite murky.

Comment: In the lore, Talia often takes a different (almost secessionist) path from her father. They do not see eye to eye in any incarnation I've seen of them. Considering that Bane follows Talia with pure devotion, "Now I am the League of Shadows" sounds more like "Now we usurped the League, who cast us out" rather than "we were never cast out from the League in the first place".

Comment: Towards the end of the movie Talia says: "He saw only a monster who could never be tamed. Whose very existence was a reminder of the hell he'd left his wife to die in. He excommunicated Bane from the League of Shadows. His only crime was that he loved me. I could not truly forgive my father..." So in a way he was excommunicated because of his looks.

Comment: @Anxhr .... I'm not sure I would go as far as saying that relates just to looks. "Monster who could never be tames" may just reflect the fact that he is too extreme, like Alfred indicates.  However it is good detail that I may add to the answer.

Comment: @Anxhr: The quote used doesn't suggest looks as the driving force (though I'm sure the mask doesn't particularly diminish it either), but rather that Bane himself acts as a reminder - no matter what he looked like.

Comment: @Flater I agree, sorry about my previous vague expression. I think Bane was an unpleasant reminder to Ra's, with or without the mask. Even his brutality could serve as a reminder, as it was likely a consequence of the place that formed him and where Ra's child was forced to grow up as well.